# Nested heredoc in shell

Tags: shell-script, shell

How can I get nested heredocs working in a shell script? It doesn't seem to recognize the EOF.

````
#!/bin/bash

test(){

    cat > /users/shared/test.sh << EOF
#!/bin/bash

check_VPN_status(){
# Returns vpn_status as connected // disconnected

    anyconnect_status=$(/opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn status | grep 'Connected')
    globalprotect_status=$(ifconfig | grep -c flags=8050)

    if [[ ! -z $anyconnect_status \
        || $globalprotect_status == 0 && -d /Applications/GlobalProtect.app ]]; then
        vpn_status=connected
        else
        vpn_status=disconnected
    fi
}

create_pf_conf(){

# Set the network interface to be used
if="en0"

# Set ports to be allowed
allowed_ports="{22}"

cat > "$pfconf" << EOF

# Default Deny Policy
block in all

# Skip the loop back interface
set skip on lo0

# Allowed inbound ports
pass in quick on $if proto tcp to any port $allowed_ports keep state

EOF
}

#----------------------------------------------------------#
#                         Global Variables                 #
#----------------------------------------------------------#

pfconf="/var/client/pf.conf"

#----------------------------------------------------------#
#                         Start Workflow                   #
#----------------------------------------------------------#


# Check if firewall is enabled and enable if needed
enable_firewall

# Get VPN connection status
check_VPN_status

if [[ $vpn_status == "connected" ]]; then
    # If connected to VPN, create pf.conf and enable pf
    create_pf_conf
    /sbin/pfctl -e -f $pfconf
else
    # If disconnected from VPN, disable pf
    /sbin/pfctl -d
fi

}

    EOF

/bin/echo "hi"
test```
````

Answer (score 1):

Just use any other "Identifier" instead of EOF for the outer heredoc.

```
    cat > /users/shared/test.sh << ABC

    # ... inner heredoc using EOF goes here...

    ABC
```

See the Documentation at https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html

It says: "Choose a limit string sufficiently unusual that it will not occur anywhere in the command list and confuse matters."

Answer (score 1):

You've apparently got several nested heredocs inside of one another, so you'll have to give each one a unique named set of `EOF` <s>markers</s> delimiters. It doesn't need to be called "EOF" btw, it can be any string as long as the one at the start and end match and all ending delimiters have no indentation (unlike the last one in your code).

Comment: There's no 'same' indentation; the marker (delmiter) must be _unindented_ (at the margin) -- unless you use `<<-word` then (any amount of) leading tabs (but not spaces) are dropped from the body _and_ ignored/accepted from the delimiter.

Comment: I meant to refer to OP's indented `EOF` at the end of the document, but I worded it very poorly.